# .setText method will not work

Tags: android, settext

I'm trying to get a string value from a listview and put into another view. I've managed to do this successfully for my first listview but it won't seem to work for my third. ( I managed to get it to work but its stopped working now for reasons I cant understand) I am using the exact same method and the information i'm trying to retrieve is being retrieved as I have confirmed while running the problem is   its just not getting changed.

Code

```
 public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.statseditor);
     dbHelper = new PlayerStatsDatabase(this);
      dbHelper.open();
     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
     if(extras !=null){
         //String value = extras.getString("Name");
     }
      //Clean all data
    //  dbHelper.deleteAllStats();
      //Add some data
      //dbHelper.insertSomeCountries();

      //Generate ListView from SQLite Database
      //displayListView();
    // list = getListView();
      PlayerNameText = extras.getString("Name");
     btnSave2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSaveStats);
     btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClearStats);
    txtGoalsScored = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtGoal);
    txtMinutesPlayed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMinPlayed);
    txtSubstituteIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSubIn);
    txtSubstituteOut = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSubOut);
    radioSubIn = (RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.rdoSubIn);
    radioSubOut = (RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.rdoSubOut);
    playerRating = (RatingBar) findViewById (R.id.ratingBar1);
    //playerTitle = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textTitle);
    playerName = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);
    playerName.setText(PlayerNameText); 
    //playerTitle.setText (PlayerNameText);
    checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById (R.id.checkBox1);
    if  (checkBox.isChecked()){
        checkBox.append("Booked");
    }
    final CharSequence checkText = checkBox.getText();
    //final Context context = 
 btnSave2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PlayerStatsDatabase db = new PlayerStatsDatabase(getApplicationContext());
            db.open();
            db.createStats(txtGoalsScored.getText().toString(),  txtMinutesPlayed.getText().toString(),txtSubstituteIn.getText().toString(),txtSubstituteOut.getText().toString(), checkText.toString());
            db.close();
            dipsplayPlayerName();
            displayListView();

            //Intent intent = new Intent(context, ListItemsActivity.class);
              //  startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
 }
```

In this first instance where I use this method `playerName` actually gets changed to `PlayerNameText`
But further down when I try to use it again it doesnt work

```
private void dipsplayPlayerName() {
    setContentView (R.layout.statslist);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    PlayerNameText = extras.getString("Name"); 
     playerTitle = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textTitle);
     playerTitle.setText (PlayerNameText);

}
```

Any ideas? The is no LogCat as the app doesnt crash

Comment: Where do you first instantiate the `Intent` to send? Have you confirmed that "Name" has a value there?

Comment: Yes I have becuase like I said the first instance of the method works as intended. And while running if I check "Name" it has the value i'm looking for.

Comment: Do you ever recreate the `view` by creating a new instance of the `Activity` or by calling `invalidate()`? Its a bit confusing which part is and isn't working here

Comment: Its for 2 different view The firstBit is working i.e the first View I use the method. But it isnt working for the displayPlayerName method. displayPlayerName method is called at the end of the onCreate Method if that helps

Comment: Why are you changing your `layout`? This isn't often a good idea but I'm not sure if its your problem at this point. But why would you use one `layout` then change it within `onCreate()`? If you need that `View` then put it in the `layout` that you first call

Comment: Also, if you declare this in `onCreate()`  `PlayerNameText = extras.getString("Name");` why would you do it again in a method declared in `onCreate()`? Why would it be different? Maybe I don't understand what you are doing

Comment: I'm not changing the layout within onCreate infact that's the sole purpose of the displayPlayerName method because its a different listview that I want to access and not the listview on the onCreate. Therefore I cant put the code inside onCreate as it refers to a different view.

Comment: I'll edit with the full code

Comment: So, `displayPlayerName()` is in the same `Avtivity` as you are showing? And, after clicking the `Button`, the text doesn't change?

Comment: Yes its in the same activity and correct the text doesn't change.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28582/discussion-between-user2268970-and-codemagic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the text data you received into a field and use it instead of getting it from the intent again.

Also, check that displayListView() doesn't change the textView.

Comment: displayView doesnt change the TextView as it has a different layout. About what you're suggesting isnt that what I did with ` PlayerNameText = extras.getString("Name");` ? If not how would I put this in a field because I can't use it without calling the bundle first.

Comment: @user2268970 I don't understand. A field is a variable that belongs to a class. Just create one for the text to be saved and used, and use it instead of accessing the intent again and again. set it just once and then use it for the next times.